# fundamental code misunderstanding

Tags: python, variables, printing, while-loop

A few days ago I bought a book called "Python for Kids (For Dummies)".
On page 47 there is an example of a simple block of code:

```
a = 2
while a < 10:
    a = a + 1
    print (a)
```

This results in the sequence:

```
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I think this result is incorrect because:

- '2' is not printed out despite being declared in the first line of the code.
- '10' is printed out, even though 10 is equal to itself (violating the condition `a < 10`).

Even if I make the 'while' condition `a <= 10`, it prints out the numbers 3 to 11 which is again incorrect.

What I think should be the correct code is as follows:

```
a = 2
while a < 10:
    print (a)
    a = a + 1
```

Resulting in:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This is what I was expecting from the code. I played a little bit with the code and interestingly enough Python allows some strange arrangements which are executable without errors yet totally incorrect! For example:

```
a = 2
while a < 30:
    a = a + 5
print (a)
```

This results in only the number '32', which seems to be incorrect.

If I indent `print (a)` by 4 spaces, I get:

```
7 12 17 22 27 32
```

This also seems to be incorrect. Can you explain to me why I'm getting these outputs?

Comment: Code is executed line by line. Unwrap the while loop, and you'll easily see the increment and print are done before the next condition is checked

Comment: You really shouldn't assume that everyone but you is wrong.

Comment: welcome to the strange world of computer programming :)

Comment: A computer program does exactly what you tell it to do. So any mistakes it makes are entirely your own responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what is supposed to happen.  The condition of a **while** or **for** loop is tested *only* at the top of the loop; there is no testing during the loop operation.  Thus, you can change the loop control variable (**a** in this case) as much as you like in the loop body, and the **while** clause will not react until you return to the top of the loop.  Equivalent code to your last example would be something like this:

```
a = 2
while True:
    if not a < 30:
        break
    a = a + 5

print (a)
```

The loop does not exit until **a** receives a value that violates the **while** condition.  If you print after **a** is updated, you *guarantee* that the last value of **a** will violate that condition.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code, notice the line before the `print` statement: it adds 1 to `a` before any printing is ever done.  Of course, if you change the code, the outcome may be different.  So unless your book claims that the output that should be produced is different from what is actually produced, the book is not wrong.

Instead of assuming that Python is *wrong*, maybe you should consider the possibility that you are misunderstanding how Python works.

Answer (score 1):

I will step through the execution of this example, one statement at a time so you can see:

```
(1) a = 2
(2) while a < 10:
(3)     a = a + 1
(4)     print (a)
```

- Line 1: Set `a` to 2.
- Line 2: Test if `a` is less than 10. It is! So we enter the `while` loop body:
- Line 3: Increase `a` by 1. `a` is now 3.
- Line 4: **Print `a` (which is 3).**
- Line 2: Return to top of loop to test the loop condition: Test if `a` is less than 10. It is! Enter the `while` loop body for the second time.
- Line 3: Increase `a` by 1. `a` is now 4.
- Line 4: **Print `a` (which is 4).**
- Line 2: Test the loop condition: `a` is still less than 10. Continue executing the loop body.
- Line 3: Increase `a` by 1. `a` is now 5.
- Line 4: **Print `a` (which is 5).**
- Line 2: Test the loop condition: `a` is still less than 10. Continue executing the loop body.
- Line 3: Increase `a` by 1. `a` is now 6.
- Line 4: **Print `a` (which is 6).**
- Line 2: Test the loop condition: `a` is still less than 10. Continue executing the loop body.
- Line 3: Increase `a` by 1. `a` is now 7.
- Line 4: **Print `a` (which is 7).**
- Line 2: Test the loop condition: `a` is still less than 10. Continue executing the loop body.
- Line 3: Increase `a` by 1. `a` is now 8.
- Line 4: **Print `a` (which is 8).**
- Line 2: Test the loop condition: `a` is still less than 10. Continue executing the loop body.
- Line 3: Increase `a` by 1. `a` is now 9.
- Line 4: **Print `a` (which is 9).**
- Line 2: Test the loop condition: `a` is still less than 10. Continue executing the loop body.
- Line 3: Increase `a` by 1. `a` is now 10.
- Line 4: **Print `a` (which is 10).**
- Line 2: Test the loop condition: `a` is not less than 10. The loop is finished. Execution continues with the next statement after the loop. If there is nothing more, the program ends.

I hope you can see from this that Python is working correctly and the output is not strange.

If you move `print (a)` above `a = a + 1` then it will print the value just before increasing it, hence why it gives an output of 2 to 9 instead of 3 to 10.

> Python allows some strange arrangements which are executable without errors yet totally incorrect! For example:
>
> ```
>   a = 2
>   while a < 30:
>       a = a + 5
>   print (a)
> ```
>
> This results in only the number '32', which seems to be incorrect.

Computers do exactly what you tell them to, which is their strength and their weakness. In your modified code, `a` is increased by 5 while it is less than 30. So it increases from 2 → 7 → 12 → 17 → 22 → 27 → 32. Then it exits that loop, since 32 is not less than 30. Then it prints `a`, which is 32. Because the print statement is not indented, it is outside the loop, so it is not executed until after the loop is finished.